# How to send error message to slack using webhook and Python?

Tags: python, slack

I have several Python functions. In case of any error I want to send the error message to slack. For this I have added below line in except block of my code-

```
    except Exception as ex:
     msg = 'There is a problem with csv generation due to: {}'.format(ex)
     logger.info(msg)
     send_message("web_hook_url",msg)
```

My send_message() looks like below-

```
def send_message(webhook_url, message):
 response = requests.post(
     webhook_url, data=json.dumps(message),
     headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
 )
 if response.status_code != 200:
     raise ValueError(
         'Request to slack returned an error %s, the response is:\n%s'
         % (response.status_code, response.text)
     )
```

I saw the following link [slack webhook post](https://gist.github.com/devStepsize/b1b795309a217d24566dcc0ad136f784) But I am confused here how to use my send_message() in my except block of code?

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data in the request needs to be in the correct format, so..

```
logger.info(msg)
slackmsg = {"text": msg}
send_message(self, slackmsg)
```

Comment: Thanks Zak! I am able to do it now :)

Answer (score 1):

your payload must have a key named "text" in it.

```
def send_message(self, message):
    payload = {"text": message}
    try:
        return requests.post(self.url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print e.message
        return False
```

And to your question how to use it, you can format your message like this:

```
{
    "message": ex.message

}
```

Also take a look on this tool [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/)

Comment: Amir, what is the current_app here? Should I use logger.error(e) only? And my except block looks fine?

Comment: sorry that was from my app, you can use simple python logger here to print it

Comment: please take a look on this `payload = {"text": message}`, you need to send payload in this form to slack webhook url

Comment: can you please edit my except block and share what should be modified there?

Comment: Thanks Amir, it was really helpful!